# Ubuntu 16.04 setup failed and now trapped in guest mode

Tags: system-installation, users

I got a Dell XPS13 with a pre-installed Ubuntu 16.04. As I turned on the computer, the setup started, asking me to input the wifi password. Something went wrong (maybe the wrong password) and ubuntu displayed a message saying that I would be put in guest mode so that I can fix the problem. How can I resume the setup process? Now every time I boot the laptop it just shows me the login screen with the guest account.

I'm not looking at a way of creating a new user, but to resume the default setup application (setting passwords, time zones, keyboard, etc.)

Thanks